# In single-threaded applications, is that one and only thread a kernel thread?

Tags: multithreading

From Wikipedia it says:

*A kernel thread is the "lightest" unit of kernel scheduling. **At least one kernel thread exists within each process.***

I've learned that a process is a container that houses memory space, file handles, device handles, system resources, etc... and the thread is the one that really gets scheduled by the kernel.

So in single-threaded applications, is that one thread(main thread i believe) a kernel thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_thread

According to that article, in a single threaded application, since you have only one thread by definition, it has to be a kernel thread, otherwise it will not get scheduled and will not run.

If you had more than one thread in your application, then it would depend on how user mode multi threading is implemented (kernel threads, fibers, etc ...).

It's important to note however it would be a kernel thread running *in user mode*, when executing the application code (unless you make a system call). Any attempt to execute a protected instruction when running in user mode would cause a fault that will eventually lead to the process being terminated.

So kernel thread here not to be confused with supervisor/privileged mode and kernel code.

You can execute kernel code, but you have to go through a system call gate first.

Comment: I thought so.  So, by **kernel thread running in user mode**, you're pertaining to a LWP(Lightweight Process) right?

Comment: The term LWP is related to multithreading. It comes into play when you have more than one user thread mapped 1:1 to kernel threads. This means that you can actually schedule all the threads belonging to a given process without having to switch the entire address space ( which is expensive) on that CPU. If your application is single threaded, the mechanism is the same, yes,  but without the benefits.

Answer (score 1):

No. In modern operating systems applications and the kernel run at different processor protection levels (often called rings). For example, Intel CPUs have four protection levels. Kernel code runs at Ring 0 (kernel mode) and is able to execute the most privileged processor instructions, whereas application code runs at Ring 3 (user mode) and is not allowed to execute certain operations. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(computer_security)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but I think the "ring level" or "protection mode" of a set of instructions is orthogonal to the OP's question, which is about distinct kernel-scheduled execution paths (regardless of protection mode of any subset of those paths) within a process.